# unable to receive form values in server using node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am submitting a form to server using angular $http post request like below

```
$scope.fileUp = function(){
    var formda = new FormData();
    for(var key in $scope.formval)
    {   
        console.log(key, $scope.formval[key]);
        formda.append(key, $scope.formval[key])
    }
    $http.post("/upload",formda, {
        transformRequest : angular.indentity,
        header : {'Content-Type' : undefined }
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
}
```

And on my node server the code is like below

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-Parser");
var multer = require("multer");
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); 
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(session({ resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, secret: 'uwotm8' }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: '150mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '150mb', extended: true}));
app.use(multer({dest : __dirname + '/public/Epub/'}))
app.post("/upload",function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body)
    console.log(request.files)
    response.json({name : "a"});
})
app.listen(8080);
console.log("server running");
```

request and response works good. i receive response.json({name : "a"}); for the request from post method on success.

The problem is on node server  console.log(request.body), 
    console.log(request.files) returns empty {} . how to receive the form data along the post request.

Wat i am doing wrong here. I am new to node js...

Comment: But your "formda" is not empty, right?

Comment: yes its is not empty

Comment: So no answer was correct in the end? No accepted nor upvoted answer. If you found the solution for this meanwhile then you should delete this post entirely as it doesn't add any value to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.fileUp = function(){
    var formda = new FormData();
    for(var key in $scope.formval)
    {   
        console.log(key, $scope.formval[key]);
        formda.append(key, $scope.formval[key]);
    }
    $http.post({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/upload',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                },
                data: formda
            }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Change nodejs code by adding app.use(bodyParser.json()):

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-Parser");
var multer = require("multer");
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); 
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(session({ resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, secret: 'uwotm8' }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: '150mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '150mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multer({dest : __dirname + '/public/Epub/'}))
app.post("/upload",function(request,response){
    console.log(request.body);
    console.log(request.files);
    response.json({name : "a"});
})
app.listen(8080);
console.log("server running");
```

Also try to avoid syntax mistakes, you are missing few semicolons in your code.

Answer (score 0):

$http post method use then function instead of success. And send the data after stringifying it.

```
            $http({
                    url:'/upload',
                    method: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify({ userName: user})
                    }).then(function (res) {
                    $log.log(res.data);
                    $log.log(res.data.userFirstName);
                 });
```

Answer (score -1):

node.js receives data in **JSON** format. In your angularjs code you are sending, **formda** object directly. You should send this object **wrapped** inside **JSON**. example:

```
var data = {"formdakey":formda}
```

Now, you should **send data object** to nodejs and in nodejs you can retrieve value of formda using below snippet:

```
var formdaval = req.body.formdakey;
```

Try this and report in case you still face issue.